# Pointer doesn't get modified in class member function

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm making a Dynamic Array with templates and classes.

This is the code I'm having issues with:

```
template<typename GType>
class GArray
{
   GType* array_type = nullptr;
   int size = 0;

public:
GArray(GType Size)
{
    size = Size;
    array_type = new GType[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        array_type[i] = NULL;
}

void Push(GType Item)
{
    size++;

    GType* temp = new GType[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
        temp[i] = array_type[i];

    temp[size] = Item;

    delete[] array_type;
    array_type = temp;
    temp = nullptr;
}

GType& operator[] (int Index)
{
    if (Index >= 0 && Index < size)
        return array_type[Index];
}
};

int main()
{
GArray<int> arr(2);
arr[0] = 10;
arr[1] = 20;
arr.Push(30);


// print array
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Size(); i++)
    cout << arr[i] << endl;

return 0;
}
```

In the main(), when I print the whole array values, the last one (which should be **30**) is an undefined value (like -842150451).

With several tests, I can say that INSIDE the Push() function, the array_type pointer changes. When I come back to the main(), it's like array_type didn't change, it's the same as before.

Comment: Your operator `[]` does not always return a value! Should not compile

Comment: Using case to determine the variable is not a good idea - typos hard to sport (line `size = Size;`)

Comment: Should learn about const and reference i.e  line `
void Push(GType Item)` should be `
void Push(const GType& Item)`

Comment: @EdHeal Missing a `return` is not a compile error in C++. With warnings enabled it should give a warning though.

Comment: @zenith - Granted it depends on the compiler. Should make the settings so that it does not compile as it is an error

Comment: @EdHeal how do I activate that warning flag in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, the standard defines it as UB: "Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a `return` with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function." — In clang and gcc `-Werror=return-type` can be used to emit an error.

Comment: @Michele - You set the warning level for the compiler. You have to google it as I have not used VS for a while

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the bug is that

```
temp[size] = Item
```

Is wrong. It should be replaced by

```
temp[size-1] = Item
```